# Links to blend at Blend Exchange and https issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, blend-exchange

I saw today that pasting links from Blend Exchanges gives this error:

[image: 1]

I've checked older answers/questions with Blend Exchange links, and images are still working fine (error shows up when you try to edit), but adding new ones gives only text link.

Do GiantCowFilms planning to switch to https:// protocol?

Or maybe better (and cheaper) solution could be changing from:

```
[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=xxxx" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/xxxx/)
```

To external image hosted on imgur:

```
[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/blend_link.png" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/xxxx/)
```

Comment: I like the cheaper solution. I do own *one* domain with an SSL cert, I might host the picture there. At least that way it will be easier to change all the images if there is a need to.

Comment: @giantcowfilms can I ask why did you use image with file id? I'm just curious as I'm mostly web dev.

Comment: Its there so if, in the future, we want to gather statistics about how many times each file's link is viewed on the page, or possibly display a unique image for each file we can. Changing all the links after the fact to achieve those goals would be nearly impossible, which is why I did it from the start despite the fact that currently it isn't used for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It has been fixed!

[image]

^^Now with SSL Certs (you can see that image link points to https). Thanks to @gandalf3 for recommending https://letsencrypt.org/, which allowed me to get **free** SSL certs for blend-exchange.

I still have to update the copy-paste on the website. I will do that soon. in the mean time links can be manually fixed

Comment: Superb! Thanks for the tip with letsencrypt.org, I will need to contact with my shared hosting provider as they don't allow using SSH.

Comment: I don't want to add another question as I think it's connected. When I try to add files to Blend Exchange it gives me error: "The provided url is not valid, please copy and paste the entire url, including the "http://" header." I'm pasting all of it as always.

Comment: @LukeD I'll look into that the url handler was updated.

Comment: I ran a batch replacement from [`http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fblend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) to [`https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fblend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com), ~2k posts affected

Comment: @m0sa Thanks!!!